# How do third party analytics work on a site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web, google-analytics

I'm just familiar with Javascript at the very basic level. My question is, how do third party sites collect data from your site, when you paste some JS code they provide on your site. For e.g, how does Google analytics or user analytics sites like Crazyegg collect used data from your site and send it to a third party? What JavaScript concepts are involved? Can you point me in the direction of some resources for the same?

Answer (score 2):

For Google analytics, how it works, you may read this article: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/

Here is explained in the `How the Asynchronous Syntax Works` chapter

Answer (score 0):

In most of cases you paste a call to a script that do an ajax call to the provider analytics server with a unique id identifing your website. Then the provider process the data and show you in a beauty way :)

Comment: It will definitively not do an ajax call due to the same-origin-policy.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [Piwik](http://piwik.org/). It's an open-source equivalent to things like Google Analytics. So, for example, you can take a look at the javascript they use to collect that data right [here](https://github.com/piwik/piwik/blob/master/js/piwik.js), as far as I can tell. You can see the [instructions on setting up tracking](http://piwik.org/docs/javascript-tracking/#toc-where-can-i-find-the-piwik-tracking-code) to learn about how the tracking is kicked off. And you can take a look at the [developer documentation](http://dev.piwik.org/trac#Developerdocumentation) to learn more about how it all works.

To answer your question (from my own ignorance): I think such systems basically run some JavaScript that gathers the data and sends it back to a server, which then displays it for you (as @Jp_uy mentioned).